# How to add a folder path to a system environment variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, environment-variables, geckodriver

I'm writing a program that uses selenium. Currently i don't think the firefox webdriver works with the current version of selenium, so I downloaded the marionette driver(wires.exe) that works well with selenium. For the wires.exe to work, it's folder's path has to be added to the system environment variables. Now i've used pyinstaller to make my program an executable file and I intend to package it with the marionette driver(wires.exe).

Now, the problem here is that the program works well on my system because I have the wires.exe path in my environment variables but when i run it on other systems it doesn't work unless the folder's path is added to the environment variables.

My question now is; is there any way to make my program add the folder's path to the environment variables because the program is for people that aren't tech savvy. Thanks.

I don't mean PYTHONPATH please, I  mean system environment variables on windows devices.

Comment: That question is about the PYHTONPATH, I'm talking about environment variables

Comment: Try adding the directory containing dll as `os.environ['PATH'] += 'C:\\Downloads'` -- Let's say `C:\Downloads` has the required DLL.

Comment: I tried that already, it doesn't work